# InfluxDB FluxResultMapper not mapping by _fields

Tags: java, influxdb

I'm trying to read measurements from the InfluxDB by using the `influxdb-client-java` and mapping the result to a POJO. Unfortunately I'm struggeling with how the internal `FluxResultMapper` is working.

Considering the following measurement
[image: Sample measurment]

When using the `QueryApi` like this

```
queryApi.query(fluxQueryString, POJO.class,
  (cancellable, fluxRecord) -> {
    LOG.info("progress: {}", fluxRecord.getProgress());
  });
```

The method `FluxResultMapper::toPojo` should do the mapping. But the implementation of this method is just mapping tags like `jobId` or `identifier` or `_time` NOT the actual fields like `progress` which are values of `_field`

Doesn't the implementation of `FluxResultMapper::toPojo` need something like this:

```
...
Map<String, Object> recordValues = record.getValues();
String col = null;
if (recordValues.containsKey(columnName)) {
  col = columnName;
} else if (recordValues.containsKey("_" + columnName)) {
  col = "_" + columnName;

// ISN'T SOMETHING LIKE THIS MISSING ???
} else if (recordValues.containsKey("_field") && 
  recordValues.get("_field").equals(columnName)) {
  col = "_value";
// END OF NEW

} else {
  String columnNameInSnakeCase = this.camelCaseToSnakeCase(columnName);
if (recordValues.containsKey(columnNameInSnakeCase)) {
  col = columnNameInSnakeCase;
}
...
```

Original code (of Version 3.1.0) can be found on [Github](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-client-java/blob/v3.1.0/client-core/src/main/java/com/influxdb/query/internal/FluxResultMapper.java)

Am I missing something or did I understand it entirely wrong? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use pivot() function to transform data into tabular form.
Please refer to [this](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-client-java/issues/245).